# Mac OSX Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, date, array, lookup

I have a list of invoice lines. Each invoice line has a supply number and this can be repeated as many times as there are invoices. Each line has a from and end date for the supply and a consumption figure.

I have another list of contracts containing supply number start date and date and price (several in fact but that’s not relevant). These are current and historic so supply number will repeat for each start and end date.

I want to look up the supply number from my invoice in the contract list and then check if the supply start date is greater than or equal to the contract start date and if the supply end date is less than or equal to the contract end date. I want then to return the price for the appropriate pair of supply number and date match.

I’ve tried lookups with a lookup, sumifs, sumproduct all in various permutations but can’t quite get it right.

Can someone help? I'm happy to post a sample file

Many thanks in advance

Comment: please share the sample file to proceed.. ( :